# Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class io.reactivex.functions.Action not found

Tags: java, android, stomp

I am using rxjava version v-2.2.6 & naiksoftware/stompprotocolandroid v-1.6.4

I keep getting this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class io.reactivex.functions.Action not found
```

anytime I add this library implementation

`'com.github.NaikSoftware:StompProtocolAndroid:1.5.2'` to my `build.gradle` file, why is this ?

```
public void connectStomp(View view) {

    List<StompHeader> headers = new ArrayList<>();
    headers.add(new StompHeader(LOGIN, "guest"));
    headers.add(new StompHeader(PASSCODE, "guest"));

    //mStompClient.withClientHeartbeat(10000).withServerHeartbeat(10000);

    resetSubscriptions();

    Disposable dispLifecycle = mStompClient.lifecycle()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(lifecycleEvent -> {
    switch (lifecycleEvent.getType()) {
    case OPENED:
    Log.e(TAG, "Stomp connection opened");
    //toast("Stomp connection opened");
    break;
    case ERROR:
    Log.e(TAG, "Stomp connection error", lifecycleEvent.getException());
    //toast("Stomp connection error");
    mStompClient.reconnect();
    break;
    case CLOSED:
    Log.e(TAG, "Stomp connection closed");
    mStompClient.disconnect();
    resetSubscriptions();
    //toast("Stomp connection closed");
    // mStompClient.connect();
    break;
    case FAILED_SERVER_HEARTBEAT:
    Log.e(TAG, "Stomp connection opened");
    //toast("Stomp failed server heartbeat");
    break;
    }
    }, throwable -> {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error on subscribe topic", throwable);
    });

    compositeDisposable.add(dispLifecycle);

    // Receive greetings
    Disposable dispTopic = mStompClient.topic("/topic/greetings")
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(topicMessage -> {
    Log.d(TAG, "Received " + topicMessage.getPayload());
    //addItem(mGson.fromJson(topicMessage.getPayload(), EchoModel.class));
    }, throwable -> {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error on subscribe topic", throwable);
    });

    compositeDisposable.add(dispTopic);

    mStompClient.connect(headers);

}
```

Comment: formatting & grammar

Answer (score 0):

NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid library is not using updated code, i had faced similar issue while integrating stomp client in android.

Refer below repository for the solution, replace the server-url and port number with you custom port and server-url.

repo- https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid

Let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55932450/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-class-io-reactivex-functions-action-not-found